# Custom environment variable script

Tags: 12.10, environment-variables

I installed ROOTv5.34.03 and it comes with a script to set the necessary environment variables.  The installation guide tells me to just run the script but that only sets the environment for that shell.  I would like to have the environment set system wide.  I found that running the script from bash_completion works as far as I can tell.  Is this an acceptable solution, is there a better way? I am using ubuntu 12.10 64-bit.  Also the script sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH so I can't place it in many common locations or else LD_LIBRARY_PATH gets erased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that /etc/profile is a better place if you want it for all users in the system. An other good place is to add it to /etc/profile.d/, just make sure that it ends with a .sh.

Comment: I have tried that but it requires that I define the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable in etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf.  I would rather have a single change in case I need to erase or change the variable values.  But I guess I'm asking if my solution is harmful I'm any way.

Comment: If you want to change the values I would recommend ~/.bashrc That file get sourced every time you start a new shell.

Comment: Well then putting the script in bash_completion should be fine as out gets used at the end of ~/.bashrc, right?